# Returning value from callback within Meteor.method

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, meteor, undefined

I am running into something I don't understand with Meteor. I have this method, which takes a query, sends it to amazon, and then in the callback of that function I try to return the results.

```
Meteor.methods({
    'search': function(query) {
        var bookInfo;
        if (Meteor.isServer) {
            amazon.execute('ItemSearch', {
                'SearchIndex': 'Books',
                'Keywords': query,
                'ResponseGroup': 'ItemAttributes'
            }, function(results) {
                bookInfo = results;
                console.log(bookInfo);
                return bookInfo;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

But when I put the following into the console in my browser (chrome):

```
Meteor.call('search', 'harry potter', function(error, response) {
    console.log('response:', response);
});
```

I get the this:

```
undefined
response: undefined          VM13464:3
```

I think I understand that the first undefined comes from the method not returning anything on the client, but the callback doesn't seem to work at all.

The amazon.execute(...) is definitely returning something, as the console.log right above the return does log the info I'm looking for.

Any ideas what's going wrong and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to use **Future** to achieve your goal.

How to use future since Meteor 0.6?

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
 Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');

 // use Future here
}
```

Your method rewritten with Future:

```
Meteor.methods({
 'search': function(query) {

    var future = new Future();

    amazon.execute('ItemSearch', {
            'SearchIndex': 'Books',
            'Keywords': query,
            'ResponseGroup': 'ItemAttributes'
    }, function(results) {
       console.log(results);

       future["return"](results)

    });

    return future.wait();
 }
});
```

Now it should work.

```
Meteor.call('search', 'harry potter', function(error, response) {
   if(error){
    console.log('ERROR :', error);
   }else{
    console.log('response:', response);
   }

});
```

If you want to learn more about **Future** library I recommend watching [screencast](https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/kXR6nWTKNctKariSY)

---

Update on 26/12/2017

I just wanted to update this answer as you can achieve the same thing using promise and so, get rid of the "fibers" depedencies :)

An example is worth a thousand words

```
import scrap from 'scrap';

Meteor.methods({
    'hof.add'(el) {
        check(el, {
            _link: String
        });

        const promise = getHofInfo(el._link)
            .then((inserter) => {
                inserter.owner = Meteor.userId();
                Hof.insert(inserter);
                return true;
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                throw new Meteor.Error('500', e.message);
            });
        return promise.await();
    }
});


function getHofInfo(_link) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        scrap(_link, function (err, $) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                const attakers = $('#report-attackers').find('li').text();
                const defender = $('#report-defenders').find('li').text();
                const _name = attakers + ' vs ' + defender;
                const _date = new Date();
                resolve({ _name, _date, _link });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: I am also facing this problem. But i don't want use an npm module. Is there any meteor package for this like fiber future

Comment: @MariyaJames check the new edit, you can do it w/o the module

Answer (score 1):

For anyone new to Meteor seeing this question and wondering *why* a library like Future or Fiber is necessary, it's because that call to **amazon.execute** is asynchronous.

In Javascript, many operations that take an extended period of time don't run one line after the next; Examples like writing to a database, using *window.setTimeout*, or making HTTP requests. With methods like these, historically you've needed to wrap the code you want to run after the fact in a **callback**.

Future and Fibers provide syntactic sugar and additional functionality, but their core functionality is the same.

Meteor uses special behind-the-scenes tricks to make certain built-in operations (like accessing MongoDB) **appear** synchronous, while still taking advantage of the increased performance of asynchronous code. For this reason, you normally only have to worry about async when using external packages (like the Amazon one in this example).

---

[Here](http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Async_on_server)'s a fully fleshed-out example of using both Future and Fibers:

There are some great articles explaining the nature of Sync/Async in Meteor on [the Discover Meteor blog](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/understanding-sync-async-javascript-node/) and at [the Meteor Chef](https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/synchronous-methods/)

Answer (score 1):

Meteor methods are asynchronous, you can get the result by many way.

Using npm module fibers (The other answer are explaining it very clearly).

There are some other way w/o using npm module :

Via Session variable :

```
    Meteor.call('myMethod',args, function(error, result) { 
  if (error) { Session.set('result', error) } // Note that the error is returned synchronously 
  else { 
    Session.set('result', result) // Using : Session.get('result') will return you the result of the meteor call !
  }
});
```

Or Via template variable :

```
    Template.hello.onCreated(function helloOnCreated() {
  // counter starts at 0
  this.message = new ReactiveVar(0);
});

Template.hello.helpers({
  message() {
    return Template.instance().message.get();
  },
});

Template.hello.events({
  'click button'(event, instance) {
    Meteor.call('myMethod', args, function (error, result) {
      if (error) { Template.instance().message.set(error); }
      else {
        Template.instance().message.set(result);
      }
    })
  },
});
```

Hope it will help !

Answer (score 0):

[one better solution](http://meteorpedia.com/read/Async_on_server)

using Fiber package

```
var Fiber = Npm.require('fibers');
...
Meteor.methods({
    callAsync: function (args) {
        var fiber = Fiber.current;

        async(function (args) {
            ...
            fiber.run(res);
        });

        return Fiber.yield();
    }
});
```