# Undefined response from meteor method call

Tags: meteor

I am calling meteor function which has an api to fetch data from google. But before getting the result it returning from method. I know it is similar to the question  [Returning value from callback within Meteor.method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20088876/returning-value-from-callback-within-meteor-method)

But i don't want to use any npm module(future-fiber) to solve this. Is there any similar package in meteor which provide same functionality.

Comment: you can use `Meteor.wrapAsync` to make your async function to sync http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_wrapasync

Comment: I made a package that has wrapAsync return useful errors: https://atmospherejs.com/hpp/makesync Anything on the server that is asynchronous must be wrapped in a fiber, so there's no getting around that.

Comment: The call to the API has an asynchronous callback. Therefore, the callback is invoked after your function returns, and is executed outside the Fiber. Thus, undefined result occurs.

Mark is correct. If you dont want to use an npm module, your other option is to use Meteor.wrapAsync