# Meteor method after api call returning undefined

Tags: javascript, meteor, geocoding

I am using Meteor, whenever I make an api call to googles geocode and try to return values from it I get an undefined, I am using the callback to the api so there is definitely data there so I'm not sure as to what is causing it

```
callWeather = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(this.state.address);
  Meteor.call("geCoordinates", this.state.address, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log(result);
    }
  });
};

geCoordinates(address) {
  googleMapsClient.geocode({ address }, (error, data) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log(data.json.results[0].geometry.location.lat);
      return data.json.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
    }
  });
},
```

Comment: Why do you need to call the `googleMapsClient` on your server method and then return the result to the client? Why not call it from the client directly?

Comment: Whenever I would try to call from the client it would throw an error saying content-type was undefined and that access-control-allow-origin header was invalid

Comment: Ok this is very maps speciic. Maybe you add to your post what you tried on the client and the errors, that came up and also tag your post with googlemaps-api or something similar, so that the chances are higher that some google maps api experts will find your post. I think the client call is the right thing to to and you should rather focus on resolving the errors on the client than switch to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common mistake that most people do when they are starting. The problem here is that before your method code *execute the callback function*, data response is present in the client. There are many solution ot this:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20090566/6880789

But, I would recommend you to use [`Meteor.wrapAsync`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-wrapAsync) like below:

```
let getGeoCode = Meteor.wrapAsync(googleMapsClient.geocode, googleMapsClient.geocode),
data = getGeoCode({ address });  // data contains data of your callback
```

Comment: Beside this is a valid answer, I would recommend to solve this problem using the client to save server resources (imagine 10000 clients use the server to request to the google maps api, then process the data, then send back to the cleints).

Comment: @Jankapunkt Yes, I agree that solution to this problem could be solved by your approach and has benefit to do like that. I just gave a solution to the problem that is likely to be encountered in any other asynchronous process.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, I had tried using the wrapAsync before but had implemented it wrong, I'll try using @Jankapunkt idea of calling from the client, I had thought that calling from the server was the right way to do things but your definitely right, thanks for the help, but the way you told me to call from the server also worked perfectly